# RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to use `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')` in Blender 3.3
to apply all modifiers. Unfortunately, I get the error in the title and I don't get what's wrong.
I could use `modifier_apply()` as an operator but that has other problems for me, s weo I wanted to see if I could fix this problem here.

```
import bpy

for collection in [c for c in bpy.data.collections if 'M_' in c.name]:
    for obj in [o.copy() for o in collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']:
        obj.data = obj.data.copy()
        if obj.animation_data:
            obj.animation_data.action = obj.animation_data.action.copy()
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
    
    with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obj):
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target="MESH")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first mistake was that `bpy.context.active_object` is read-only. You have to use `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active` instead. Another problem was that `bpy.ops.object.convert` need the object to be selected, so I deselected all selected objects to not disturb the process. After the conversion, the selection is restored.

```
import bpy

# save and reset state of selection
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
active_object = bpy.context.active_object
for obj in selected_objects:
    obj.select_set(False)

# apply modifier by converting to mesh    
for collection in [c for c in bpy.data.collections if 'M_' in c.name]:
    for obj in collection.objects:
        obj.data = obj.data.copy()
        if obj.animation_data:
            obj.animation_data.action = obj.animation_data.action.copy()
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
            
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        selection = obj.select_get()
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target="MESH")
        obj.select_set(selection)

# restore saved state of selection
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object
for obj in selected_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Thanks Rivin, I might have a misconception of context.temp_override() then.
Because numerous lines of selection code is exactly what I didnt want.

Context overrides should take care of what you pointed out. At least I thought so!
I understood through other stackexchange questions that those overrides would be the way to go since 3.3

Comment: If I use bpy.ops.object.convert with temp_override, the modifier is applied, but I get a copy of the object. So temp_override is probably not suitable for some operators

Comment: Did you use my code snippet from above?
Then yes, it should generate a duplicate beforehand.
But temp_override() should not generate a duplicate/copy on its own, just tested with the snippet below, and was watching the blend file contents in the outliner to verify:

import bpy
    
with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=bpy.context.active_object):
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target="MESH")

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidentally deleted this one line and didn't see the copy in the outliner

Comment: @rbx775 it would have worked with any other operator but AFAIK `bpy.ops.object.convert` is not overridable, confirmed by the devs. See https://developer.blender.org/T93188 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235009/overriding-convert-object-operator-issue/235048#235048